# How to generate different levels of optimization in the same source module?

Tags: debugging, optimization, gcc, compiler-optimization

I am using GCC to build my embedded C application, that I debug with GDB. The app consists on a program running on a host processor and multiple programs running on multiple accelerator DSP cores.

My host (control) program has a very simple main function with a short loop calling a bigger function that does some stuff and activates the accelerators. My problem is that when compiling with optimization, the debug is harder in terms of breakpoint location in the main function. When building w/o optimization, the other function compiles sub-optimally.

A possible solution would be to separate the host project to two source files and use different level of optimization. However, I would like to keep it in the same file.

Is there a way (pragma?) to instruct the compiler to do different level of optimization in the same source unit?

Comment: I did answer, but why did you not look into GCC's documentation?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - Thanks for your answer. I actually had a brief look at the 600 pages gcc doc that came with my installation. Admittedly, it was brief and maybe I missed that part. Another reason is probably that since I was not aware of this option, it was more a "shot in the dark". The version we use is GCC 4.4.3 and just last week we started dealing with 4.7. So it was not available in the older release we were using, according to your answer.

Comment: FYI: 4.7 is not released yet!

Comment: Oh - the older version was 4.3.0, and not as I wrote above. Not that it really matters...

Comment: Then ask your tool guy to get a newer GCC trunk. Stage 1 (the most experimental one) of 4.7 ended a few weeks ago, so I suppose that a recent trunk (ie 4.7) is better than one from july 2011. And don't forget to update your GCC 4.7 quite often: people are correcting bugs in it right now!

Comment: Why are you optimizing any of this? The time is spent in the DSP cores. The compiler's optimization only matters in code where the program counter spends a large fraction of its time.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey - mostly, you are correct. However, this is actually a benchmark in which I call the "function" numerous times. Some init code is done on the host, and in real life application, it is performed whenever the "function" is called, so I want to make sure the init stuff is optimized as well.

Comment: You can optimize just as a matter of taste, without actually caring if it makes a real difference, but then you run up against your problem, that it's hard to debug. Personally, if I'm concerned about performance, I employ *[this technique](http://stackoverflow.com/q/927773/23771)*. Then if there's nothing else I can do, and I still want a few percent better performance, *and* if the PC's spending much time in *my* code, then I turn on the optimizer.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey - thanks for your comment. The post you linked to looks very interesting and I will go through it more thoroughly when I have more time. Also the method used, described in a subsequent post makes perfect sens and I don't know why you get objections. But anyway I don't really need that to *debug* per-se, but rather to be able to break the run at a specific place in a nested loop in the host's main(), so I can measure the time it takes to perform the (non-debug-session) "function calls" on the DSP cores. With the optimizer on, the relationship between line numbers is vague.

Comment: @ysap: The reason I get objections is like the emperor's new clothes. I'm calling the bluff of a minor industry - profiling. They say "profilers do just what you do, only faster and better", but how much speedup do they get? That link shows 43x over 8 iterations. Speedup results are something they never mention. They may say "I found a bottleneck" as if that's good enough. The reason is simple. Profilers assume all speedup opportunities are local so that localized measurement will expose them. That's why they miss them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a recent GCC (e.g. GCC **4.6**), you can change optimization with [function specific option pragmas](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html#Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas), like e.g.

```
 #pragma GCC optimize ("-02")
```

You can also have [function attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes) for the same.

IIRC, this appeared in GCC 4.5, and works much better in 4.6, so you need a recent version of GCC.